# Multiple values in a input type radio tag

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Right now I have this form.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">

    <div class="radio">
        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="hairstyle" id="optionsRadios1" value="Lang">Lang
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="hairstyle" id="optionsRadios2" value="Kort">Kort
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="hairstyle" id="optionsRadios3" value="Kaal">Kaal
        </label>
    </div>

</div>
```

When you click on the second button you get the `value Kort`. But every option costs a different time so is it possible to give it a another value   with for example 15? I tried `{'style':'min','kort':'15'}` , `kort|15` and `kort,15` but it's not working. Or is there something build in laravel I am not aware of?

Comment: not understand what you need

Comment: I just want to get two values for every option.

Comment: why not used check box? radio box return 1 only

Comment: You mean `value="Kort|15"` doesn't work?

Comment: @pov I want two values every option.

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use something like `Kort|15` and then break the two values in your controller? Since you are talking about Laravel, I'm guessing that behind the scenes (and your post) you have a controller that will handle the data. Thus, you could do something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $hairstyle = $request->input('hairstyle');
    $values = explode('|', $hairstyle);
    $name = $values[0]; //This will be Kort
    $cost = $values[1]; //This will be 15
    ...
}
```